# Render bar chart with chart.js and react and es6

Tags: reactjs, charts, ecmascript-6, react-chartjs

I am trying to use the chart.js bar chart with react and es6.

As I am using `import` instead of `require` my project looks a bit different than the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs#example-usage).

Here is an example of my project:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BarChart } from 'react-chartjs';

class HelloChart extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let data = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      }]
    };
    let options = {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }]
      }
    };
    this.state = {
      chartData: data,
      chartOptions: options,
    };
  }
  render() {
    let chartData = this.state.chartData;
    let chartOptions = this.state.chartOptions;
    return (
      <div>
        <BarChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} width="600" height="250" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HelloChart
```

These are the two errors in am getting in my console:

`Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of`HelloChart`.`

And ...

`Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of`HelloChart`.`

Answer (score 3):

This should solve your problem:

```
const BarChart = require("react-chartjs").Bar;
```

or,

```
import { Bar as BarChart } from 'react-chartjs';
```

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';

const BarChart = require('react-chartjs').Bar;

class HelloChart extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      }]
    };
    const options = {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }]
      }
    };
    this.state = {
      chartData: data,
      chartOptions: options,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { chartData, chartOptions } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <BarChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} width="600" height="250" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HelloChart;
```

Comment: Per the example, this is code I am using now: https://gist.github.com/SeanPlusPlus/c39d4f25d76dbbebfffaa10f9193d136 And the error I get is: "Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)[chartType] is not a function(…)"